# Views displaying node reference fields

Tags: views, nodes

Will the view chosen (in the advanced settings) of a node reference in a content type get overridden by another view if the node reference field is shared between two (or more) content types?

In more detail: I am working with a Drupal site that has a content type that contains a node reference field. One of the things it asks you when creating the content type is - which views are used to reference the node. I am trying to create another content type that shares the same field as the first one, and it therefore will also be a node reference.
BUT, when I create this new content type, it again asks which view I want to use. If I chose a different one will it override the view in the first content type, since they share a common field?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can have different field settings for different content types. This was not possible in Drupal 6.